# Tooltip on select box options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a select box in which the options have policy name. I need to display the description of policies in tool tip of the options. I tried tipr plugin where data-tip option is used for this. It works fine for div, span etc but not for select box option. I also tried normal method that I attached in the above link. This works only when the drop down is open by default .

```
<div>
    <h4>Default behaviours</h4>
    <select>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <h4 class='uitip' title='Tests with jQuery UI Tooltips applied'>jQuery UI tooltips</h4>
    <select class='uitip' title='has tooltips'>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple class='uitip' title='has tooltips'>
        <option title=""></option>
        <option title="1">1</option>
        <option title="2">2</option>
        <option title="3">3</option>
        <option title="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/Dp4te/

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can do it with the jquery ui `selectmenu widget` check demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Lv57G/)

Comment: This while hovering on options, displaying option value . The requirement is title of the option should be displayed :-)

Comment: You can do it by using standard bootstrap tooltip see my answer

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution below...but the solution seems to require 'multiple' be specified for the select box. Which wasn't the original question nor my situation.

Is there a way to keep the select to one choice (and one row in height) but still use your #tooltip_container workaround?

I can get tooltips using just 'title' but they look terrible and out of line with the rest of my Bootstrap tooltips on other elements.

Thank you for taking another look @ustmaestro.

Answer (score 7):

You must specify a container for tooltip outside select, because tooltip is rendered inside select and is ignored by browser. 
As is specified in twitter bootstrap documentation tooltips are by default disabled you must enable it by yourself.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#four-directions
See an working example below or https://jsfiddle.net/5xj10efa/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:80px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select name="opts" id="opts" class="form-control" multiple>
                    <option value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 1">option 1</option>
                    <option value="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 2">option 2</option>
                    <option value="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 3">option 3</option>
                    <option value="4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 4">option 4</option>
                    <option value="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 5">option 5</option>
                    <option value="6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 6">option 6</option>
                </select>
                <div id="tooltip_container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update: add a code snippet**

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:80px;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <select name="opts" id="opts" class="form-control" multiple>
      <option value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 4">option 4</option>
      <option value="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 5">option 5</option>
      <option value="6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="tooltip 6">option 6</option>
     </select>
     <div id="tooltip_container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It looks like this only works for multiple select.  Regular select ignores it