# enable bootstrap tooltip in multiselect option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, html-select

i have a problem regarding with putting bootstrap tool-tip from my options in my multi-select.

I want to use the bootstrap tooltip with a black tool-tip, but when i tried to use it in my multi-select it doesn't working. How can i put a tool-tip every option-value for my multi-select ?.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="tdiagnosis[]" id="tdiagnosis" class="form-control select2"  multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Please input diagnosis here" style="width: 178%;">
    <?php foreach($diagnosis_id as $each){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $each->diagnosis_id; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="<?php echo $each->description; ?>"><?php echo $each->diagnosis; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

and in my javascript i put like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: First of all there isn't  any attribute called `id` for `option` and with your current approach you end up creating duplicate `id` elements in `DOM`. Also, try attaching `tooltip` to something general rather than being specific..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao so what would i do for this? do you mean this doesn't fit for an option tooltip ?

Comment: Yes, it rather wouldn't fit.. Something like `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` might help..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i will put that in my javascript and remove the id ? or ? is that referring already to my option ?

Comment: Put the code from my last comment in `js` and yea remove `id` from options. That should work..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao why still not working ? :( please help me sir

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  table_hist = $('#dataTables-patienthist').dataTable();
  table_patients = $('#dataTables-patients').dataTable();
  show_allpatient();

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

Comment: I just worked on this, and I can see that `tooltip` has been appended to `DOM` on hover, but it's been misplaced. Not sure, how you can position it properly.. Let me get back to you if I find anything..

Comment: **[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360050/2065039)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao hello sir, thanks for the link, can you figure out why still it doesn't work ? . please take a look in my updated post. I edited my post, based on the answer/link you gave to me

Comment: Need some detailed info as you have some php code included. Need to whether options are loaded after page load or before page load and whether you have written `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` before option loads etc.,

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am doing the options load in my controller, thank you for your reply. Like this :public function index() {
   $user = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']);
  $data['profile'] = $this->User_model->user_info($user);   
        $data['diagnosis_id'] = $this->Clinic_model->showall_diagnosis(); 
  $this->load->view('admin/header.php',$data);
  $this->load->view('admin/myclinic_form.php');
  $this->load->view('admin/footer.php');
  }

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on `php`. But can you just let me know whether options are loaded through ajax or page load?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, thanks for your reply.  it is in getready function.  Use ready() to make a function available after the document is loaded:

Comment: Yea but I need to know whether options are loaded through `ajax` i.e. after document load?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao still have no knowledge about that sir, please help me :(