# Tooltip or comment for select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap select for my dropdowns. Im interested is it possible to add a comment or a tooltip for each option that would pop up immediatly when i hover my mouse over it? Each comment is about 20-30 words long so it dosent fit well into the list.

At the moment i just have the select element:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="">
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
<option>option3</option>
<option>option4</option>
</select>
$('select').selectpicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mfrup5bL/136/

Comment: give it a try:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359450/tooltip-on-select-box-options

Comment: here is what i ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/mfrup5bL/142/ - dosent seem to work with bootstrap select, if i remove bootstrap select it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this, it works well with bootstrap select.
The bootstrap select is an unordered list of your select options.

```js
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker()
var title = [];
$('#mySelect option').each(function(){
    title.push($(this).attr('title'));
});

$("ul.selectpicker li").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('title',title[i]).tooltip({container:"#tooltipBox"});
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="mySelect" multiple>
         <option title="Option 1">option one</option>
         <option title="Option 2">option two</option>
         <option  title="Option 3">Option three</option>
         <option title="Option 4">Option four</option>
         </select>
              <p id="tooltipBox" class="col-sm-6" style="z-index:9999;"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand what this is doing. You are assigning a tooltip value to each option and then just assiging a title value based on that tooltip. Why not just assing the title value right away?

Comment: One more problem with this solution. If i have one of the options selected then that option will already have a tooltip when opening the dropdown. Can this be avoided? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mfrup5bL/148/

Comment: If you remove `multiple` attribute from the `select` I could see the problem but if you don't there isn't any problem with the solution. The original question has `multiple` attribute enabled but let me try to figure out a solution to that.

Comment: I removed `.tooltip({container:"#tooltipBox"})` from this `$("ul.selectpicker li").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('title',title[i]);
})` and problem disappeared. But let me see if we can make it work with `tooltip()`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Working copy attached.

```
<option value="1" title="Long description">Short desc...</option>
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1" title="Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description">Short desc...</option>
  <option value="volvo" title="i AM a generic content">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" title="Long description">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" title="Long description">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" title="Long description">Audi</option>
</select>
```

To your example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select class="form-control" id="myID" name="myID" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true">
    <option title="Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description">option1</option>
    <option title="Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description">option2</option>
    <option title="Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description">option3</option>
    <option title="Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description Long description">option4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure this works with the bootstrap select like the OP mentioned?

Comment: To answer your question, I added the same in your example. You can check the second snippet which is working properly. I hope it can help you. If you see any issue, you can let me know, I will try to figure it out. But this should work as expected.

Comment: Not quite what i need. I need the tooltip to appear text appear immediately because most users wont know to hover over an option for the time needed for tooltip to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have long tooltips, or you want to use html within the tooltip:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="myID">Test</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="myID" name="myID" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
$('#myID').tooltip({'trigger':'focus', 'title': 'This is my tooltip. You can use <b>HTML</b>.'});
</script>
```

I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15o0t2ju/1/

you can change data-placement="top" to bottom, left, right.
check doc: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: Not exactly what i ment. I need an individual tooltip for each option.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn`t get that.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below example for adding comment/tooltip for each option using bootstrap.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="">
<option value="option1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="comment for option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="comment for option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="comment for option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tooltip_container" title="comment for option4">option4</option>
</select>
<div id="tooltip_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```